# Is there any synchronization system for sections/parts/ranges of files?

Tags: git, svn, version-control

Git and Subversion are great systems to synchronize source files between various locations and manage their versions.

However, sometimes it can be useful take only a **section/part/ranges of a source file and synchronize this section/part between various locations within and between projects**.

Examples scenarios of this could be:

- The 'footer' of a web page identical in various web properties (e.g. `<p>(c) My Inc. 2012</p>`).
- Small utility methods, which do not warrant the inclusion of another dependency/library (e.g. `public static byte[] fromInputStream(InputStream is);`).
- Common parts of configuration files, for instance server addresses, database login info, ...

There are other solutions to above-mentioned scenarios, but being able to synchronize sections of source files could be a viable, versatile, additional tool for many purposes.

**Do you know of any tools for synchronizing sections/parts/ranges of source files?**

(I've built a little prototype for this, which wasn't too difficult, but it would be great to know of any established system/approach, which builds on known SCM solutions).

Edit: I changed the title from asking for a versioning system to asking for a synchronization system since I think it reflects the content of the question better and in response to discussion below.

Comment: You mean like marking ranges in files for version control instead of the whole file?  Seems like you would have problems with maintaing accurate references to the "sections" if the content changes too much. Could you maybe expand on a real-world example of how you see this being used? I don't understand how you would be able to "include" partial file content into other files. If that "footer" were version controlled, how would it be included in 10 files? I would see it as just being a "footer.html" whole file.

Comment: This a separation-of-concerns issue; you should separate the concern of versioning from the concern of assembling a larger whole from a collection of pieces.  Do what it takes so the common pieces of the files are stored in only one place, and version that.

Comment: @jdi Yes, that is what I mean. I like the term 'ranges' and added it above. Yes again, the partial file would indeed become just another file. Just this 'file' can then be included in another file.

Comment: But what @antlersoft is saying is to not think about a versioning system supporting this separation concern. Implement it by splitting up your actual files into the sections, and version those.

Comment: How would it become "included" in another file? What common functionality introduces this ability? If I am writing a new configuration file that shares some commonality, how would I "include" that into the conf file? It puts quite a lot of dependency onto this versioning system. Basically I would just put the common part in a file and version it.

Comment: @antlersoft & jdi: I think you are right. Probably I am most interested in the assembly of files. Whether this is done by a source control system or is not so important. So even a tool, which is not a SCM would be helpful in the context.

Comment: @jdi I have been experimenting with something along the lines of: `<name>myProject<name> <!-- include [db conf file id] --><dbuser>user</dbuser><dbpsw>psw</dbpsw><!-- endinclude -->` - so still the db configuration common part becomes its own file with its own versions and the host file (project definition) remains its identity and version still

Comment: Yes but while your version control system could parse that and version it as its own unit...how would you then make use of that unit in other sources? Those include tags have no meaning outside of your versioning parser.

Comment: @jdi Right, therefore the include tags would have to be disguised as comments (for java/javsscript source the syntax would be something along the lines of `// <!-- include [files id]`)

Comment: 1) It still makes no sense because how would they expand? Unless you have to have some support tool that you would run on all your files to preprocess them and expand back out any "version snippet tags" 2) You would have to include foreign symbols that could conflict with the grammar of many other source types. So it should know how to properly escape these tags for every grammar?

Comment: I somewhat understand what you are getting at, regarding my first point in the previous comment. You are suggesting that N files all contain the expanded content, but wrapped with some proprietary tagging that allows it to be checked against version control for changes. Point #2 still stands though.

Comment: 1) I agree that that must happen, a preprocessor must go through the files (essentially scms have to process files in any case?) 2) maybe target a couple of grammars first (e.g. xml, js, c), the preprocessor can then be expanded to deal with more variations of the syntax